# How I can open .kmz files?

Tags: command-line

I am new in ubuntu-linux, and I was wondering if there is any way to open or view .kmz file-output through ubuntu-linux commands? Currently I'm using a macbook (XQuarts) bash-ssh connected to a remote computer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try changing the extension from .kmz to .zip and see what happens - this might be a [known problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1906131). .kmz is a [Google Earth file](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives), so this should work

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. The thing is that I can't change the extension because the KMZ is an output (ozone dispersion) created by my professor and she gave me the permission to see these folders. Here is the path that I want to look: home1:/home/mirk/ozone_dispersion_ENW4_2012091400.kmz
  I don't know how she does it, but for me this is a mystery. Thanks wilf.

Comment: Looks like you may need to open it in Google Earth. However, other programs like [Marble](http://marble.kde.org/install.php) may be able to open it. There is also a [wiki on it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language)

Comment: Ah, re-read the question. To open you will probably have to copy it to your computer using `ftp` or something. You could also use a Graphical version such as [gftp](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/gFTP) as well. This can then be used to transfer files (FTP = File Transfer Protocol) from the remote computer to yours. The problem with this though is that the remote computer would require a FTP server. Is there any other way of accessing the file?

Comment: Thanks. The only way that I can access these KMZ files is from home1 directory. I am a little confused with all this terms because I am new on this. Sorry I wasn't more specific.

Comment: What to you intend to do with it? You can open it in the `ssh` console with `gdal` commands, e.g. `gdalinfo file.kmz` or `unzip -p file.kmz` to see its `xml` contents (`kmz` is just a zipped `kml`, which itself is "just" an `xml` file with geographic contents). Or download it with `scp` or `filezilla` -> Create an `SFTP` connection to your server and open locally to view it (QGIS or Google Earth or so will open it).

Answer (score 0):

As this is one file, and as you have ssh access, this should work. It should also work most Unix systems, including Mac. I believe a Windows interface is also available.

With ssh, you can normally access the remote machine by using this command:

```
ssh username@ip_address
```

or, sometimes, this:

```
ssh ip_address -l username
```

To copy a file from one machine to another, you need to use the `scp` command. This works like the `cp` (copy) command, but works through SSH.

Just for clarification, the `cp` command works like this:

```
cp '/SOURCE/FILE' '/DESTINATION/FILE`
```

So, to use the `scp` command, use this:

```
scp 'username@ip_address:/SOURCE/FILE' '/DESTINATION/FILE`
```

So in your case, I think it would be something like this:

```
scp 'username@ip_address:/home/mirk/ozone_dispersion_ENW4_2012091400.kmz 'WHICH/FOLDER/YOU/WANT/TO/PUT/IT/IN/ozone_dispersion_ENW4_2012091400.kmz'
```

You should then have it on your computer, and then be able to open it using Google earth, or some other .kmz reading program - some are listed [here](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/kmz).

I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using one of Googles sample kmz files as example:

```
$ unzip -t 080505-__D-Day_Invasion_Normandy_WW_II_[20548].kmz
Archive:  080505-__D-Day_Invasion_Normandy_WW_II_[20548].kmz
    testing: doc.kml                  OK
    testing: images/normandy.gif      OK
No errors detected in compressed data of 080505-__D-Day_Invasion_Normandy_WW_II_[20548].kmz.

$ unzip -p 080505-__D-Day_Invasion_Normandy_WW_II_[20548].kmz doc.kml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
<GroundOverlay>
  <name>Invasion Normandy </name>
  <Icon>
    <href>images/normandy.gif</href>
    <viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale>
  </Icon>
  <LatLonBox>
    <north>54.68344948353803</north>
    <south>47.72497849401205</south>
    <east>8.067729910987291</east>
    <west>-5.840828344018727</west>
    <rotation>5.28805241062117</rotation>
  </LatLonBox>
</GroundOverlay>
</kml>
```